# How do I use join and indexBy in Yii2?

Tags: join, activerecord, yii2

I have this, but it loads each and every `ebay` row individually, generating thousands of SQL statements:

```php
$products = \app\models\Product::find()
    ->joinWith('ebay', false, 'inner join')
    ->indexBy(function($row){return $row->ebay->epid;})
    ->all();
```

I tried this, but it gave an error: `'Getting unknown property: app\models\Product::ebay.epid'`

```php
$products = \app\models\Product::find()
    ->joinWith('ebay', false, 'inner join')
    ->indexBy('ebay.epid')
    ->all();
```

Setting eager loading = `true` doesn't help either. It still loads each row individually then loads them again at the end.

How can I *efficiently* join a table in Yii and index by a value in the joined table?

Comment: Do you have a Product::getEbay() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with `indexBy`. However, `ArrayHelper::index` can index an array on a related model field. So here's how it can be done:

```
$products = \app\models\Product::find()
    ->with('ebay')
    ->all();

ArrayHelper::index($products, 'ebay.epid');
```

The code will run two queries, one to get all products, one to get all related ebay products. Then the array will be indexed with no DB queries at all.

Comment: Wow, that worked! I didn't know that existed. I love learning about new things! Had to use `$products = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::index($products, 'ebay.epid');`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it manually for a subset of the ids and it only uses 2 queries. I'd still be interested in the `indexBy` though.

```
$products = Product::find()->joinWith('ebay', true, 'inner join')->where(['ebay.epid' => $productIds])->all();
$ebayProducts = array();
foreach ($products as $p) {
  $ebayProducts[$p->ebay->epid] = $p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want index by relation recods via joinWith() or with() results you can use following:

```
->with(['relationName' => function($q) {
            $q->indexBy('field_name');
        }])
```